# Error in Lists in Haskell - Intersection

Tags: haskell

This is a tiny problem, I really don't know where I've be wrong. I need to create a function for show the intersection of two lists (without library and list comprehension). Ok, I made this, it's simple, but I have make a mistake, cause the function return me only the first element equal of the two lists. This is a stupid error, I know. someone can Help me?

this is the function:

```
inter :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
inter [] _ = []
inter _ [] = []
inter (x:xs) (y:ys) | (x == y) = x:[]
                    | otherwise = inter xs ys
```

example of error: (Two lists) [1,2,4] [1,3,4]

return only [1] when the correct is: [1,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over both lists simultaneously and stopping at the first common element.  You need to be checking list membership and continuing after you find the first matching element.  I would recommend using the `elem` function:

```
inter (x:xs) ys | elem x ys = ...
                | otherwise = inter xs ys
```

You'll need to fill in the `...` here, I intentionally left it blank for you to figure out what you need to do.

In your function what's going to happen is it will see

```
inter (1:2:4:[]) (1:3:4:[])
```

And it will assign `x = 1, y = 1, xs = 2:4:[], ys = 3:4:[]`, then compute `x == y`, which evaluates as `True`, so that branch is chosen, returning `x : []`. or `[1]`.  At that point the function returns.  It'll never check `2 == 3` or `4 == 4`.

Comment: Thanks for the Help and the explantion! 
inter (x:xs) ys | elem x ys = x : inter xs ys

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: a set is a *sorted* list here.

Your code works as follows:

```
inter :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
inter [] _ = []
inter _ [] = []
inter (x:xs) (y:ys) | (x == y) = x:[]         -- if x == y, we stop?
                    | otherwise = inter xs ys -- can we drop both elements?
```

The first two lines state that "*from the moment one of the lists is `[]`, we return `[]`*". So far so good.

Then next line works with two guards. Given we find that the two *heads* are equal (`x == y`), we simply return *a list with one item `[x]`. That is not correct: it is possible that in the two tails `xs` and `ys`, there are still items that are in both sets. The second guard is incorrect as well: if `x` is not equal to `y`, that does not mean we can throw away both elements: it is possible that `x` is still in the tail `ys`, or that `y` is still in `xs` somewhere.

We can however obtain a rather efficient solution by the fact that both lists are sorted. In that case, we can simply drop the smallest of the two. Since if `ys` is sorted and `x < y`, we know that all elements in `ys` will also be greater than `x`.

So a solution I propose is:

```
inter :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
inter [] _ = []  -- left list is empty, stop
inter _ [] = []  -- right list is empty, stop
inter xa@(x:xs) ya@(y:ys) | x == y = x : inter xs ys -- both head same, continue
                          | x < y = inter xs ya      -- left less, step left
                          | otherwise = inter xa ys  -- right less, step right
```

The `@` is an alias here. `xa@(x:xs)` means that we have a reference to the entire list `xa` and to the head `x` and the tail `xs`.

Usually one aims to be as generic as possible in Haskell: right now we have to implement an `inter` for lists with `Int`s, `String`s, etc. That is not very elegantly. We can generalize it to the following:

```
inter :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
inter [] _ = []
inter _ [] = []
inter xa@(x:xs) ya@(y:ys) | x == y = x : inter xs ys
                          | x < y = inter xs ya
                          | otherwise = inter xa ys
```

Comment: Great! This is other method to do this function, thanks.